# Discord.js result poll command that needs some work

Tags: javascript

I am having a problem with my discord.js bot, where I have a poll command, but I want it to see how many reactions it has after a certain amount of time that the user asks for, then say (There are more people who prefer x than people who prefer y).

discord.js:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')

exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
  if (!args) return message.reply("You must have something to vote for!")
  if (!message.content.includes("?")) return message.reply("Include a ? in your vote!")
    message.channel.send(`:ballot_box:  ${message.author.username} started a vote! React to my next message to vote on it. :ballot_box: `);
    const pollTopic = await message.channel.send(`${args}`);
    pollTopic.react(`✅`);
    pollTopic.react(`⛔`);
};
```

Comment: What problems are you encountering? What didn't work? Please help us help you :)

Comment: Sorry about that xD, Im not having any specific answers, im just basically asking the question "How do you find out how many more reactions does  ✅ have than ⛔, or vice versa

Answer (score 3):

```
if (!args) return message.reply("You must have something to vote for!")
if (!message.content.includes("?")) return message.reply("Include a ? in your vote!")
message.channel.send(`:ballot_box:  ${message.author.username} started a vote! React to my next message to vote on it. :ballot_box: `);
const pollTopic = await message.channel.send(message.content.slice(2));
await pollTopic.react(`✅`);
await pollTopic.react(`⛔`);
// Create a reaction collector
const filter = (reaction) => reaction.emoji.name === '✅';
const collector = pollTopic.createReactionCollector(filter, { time: 15000 });
collector.on('collect', r => console.log(`Collected ${r.emoji.name}`));
collector.on('end', collected => console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} items`));
```

I tried this on my own bot and what it did was > Firstly the prefix i used was just ai which is why i just sent the message.content but sliced 2. I made a reaction collector with the help of the [Discord.js documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=reactions).
After 15 seconds it will console.log the amount of people who have reacted with the emoji ✅. Just look at my code and you can bend it to your preferences. If you didnt understand or you want me to further explain, or "i did something wrong" then reply back to me.